# Are buffer overflows pretty much a thing of the past in 2020

Tags: buffer-overflow

After learning about buffer overflows: In the 90's finding a buffer overflow nearly always meant you could exploit it.

Nowadays there are a lot of protection mechanisms like address layout space randomization, making memory either executable or writeable, stack cookies, ...

It seems to me that with only 1 protection mechanism in place, you can get around it (for example with return orientated programming). But when you combine these protection mechanisms, the door is pretty much shut down. And if someone finds an overflowable buffer there is a 95 percent chance it's not exploitable.

It seems to me that the only way buffer overflows are reliably exploitable is if these protections are not in place, but operating systems force these protections

So are buffer overflow attacks pretty much dead nowadays?

Comment: The Heartbleed bug was not so long ago (2014).  While this was not a typical buffer overflow bug in the sense that the bug caused the program to overrun the buffer while writing to it, it was in fact a buffer overflow bug in that the bug caused the program to read past the end of the buffer.  See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23089964/is-the-heartbleed-bug-a-manifestation-of-the-classic-buffer-overflow-exploit-in

Comment: Your description of existing security mechanisms might reflect the user space of recent OS for server, desktop and mobile devices, but is far less applicable to OS kernel (including drivers) and smaller embedded systems. Also, running 20 year old software is not uncommon in industrial context, i.e. the terrible past is actually still present. But yes, buffer overflow is less used compared too all the other attacks. 20 years ago all the web based attacks did not matter that much as they do today.

Comment: This is just bad logic: "because something should not have a reason to exist, then, therefore, it does not exist". If you wanted to know if there *were* BO vulns, you can search for that. Here is a list of buffer overflow vulnerabilities found in 2020: https://cve.mitre.org/cgi-bin/cvekey.cgi?keyword=buffer+overflow

Comment: @schroeder While I agree that the logic is flawed I can understand if when your new to it and just learned about all that great stuff we have that you might think “surely this is a fixed thing now”. Your list of mitre conclusively proofs that to be false but I still get the thought pattern.

Comment: Response to the last 2 answers. I understand that there may be a flaw in my logic. Please tell me where the flaw is then because i want to learn new things. That list proves nothing cause 95 percent not exploitable is not the same as a 100 percent, read the post again. But maybe i should delve into that list to learn. I dont want to start a long discussion but if my logic is flawed please tell me where the fault is i just want to learn

Comment: Boothole is a buffer overflow vulnerability. We'll be fixing that for years

Comment: _"operating systems force these protections"_ not necessarily,  some protections must be enabled on a program-by program basis at compile time.

Comment: I have explained the flaw in logic. And your "95%/100%" comments are meaningless. Nothing is ever 100% and even 5% is enough to cause serious concern.

Comment: I would have to agree with @schroeder, there was a video presentation from Joe McCray on exploiting buffer overflows. In the presentation, vulnerability in software (he used for demonstration) wasn't some edge case programming, but something that anyone could implement by a mistake. 
It happens now, and probably will in year of 2040.

Answer (score 4):

While it is shocking, buffer overflows (alongside other memory corruption vulnerabilities) are still very much a thing of the present.

Due to exploit mitigations and hardening used by modern systems, it becomes much harder or impossible to exploit many of these vulnerabilities. However, many vulnerabilities are still introduced and/or found, as many new projects today are still written in unsafe languages, and many existing projects (e.g. Linux) written in these unsafe languages cannot easily be rewritten (yes, I'm aware there have been attempts to write kernels in Rust, but the language is probably very far from replacing the entire kernel codebase).

Anecdotally, I have found several buffer overflows this year in new code, or sometimes old code being reused for a new product. Some of them only amounted to denial of service, but others resulted in remote code execution. In some cases, it was easy to exploit them due to lack of exploit mitigations (e.g. many consumer-grade IoT devices have binaries compiled without mitigations), but other times, while more challenging, most of the mitigations could be circumvented.

In short, memory corruption vulnerabilities may never fully be eliminated as long as computer systems are not perfect; even a "safe" language can have bugs.

Answer (score 1):

Buffer overflow (and under flow) will always exist.
(Or at-least for as long as non memory safe languages are being used. Since assembly is memory unsafe and still needed to create same parts we still have the risk)

While we can employ protections against memory abuse (using a vm, memory safe languages like rust, compiler validation like in Golang.) there is no way know to us that can prove a piece of software is free from fault (this includes memory faults)

We must also consider that at many places we still can not use the tools we might like due too:

- license issues
- libraries in use
- legacy code in use
- processors in use
- embedded environment limitations
- Use of a fpga (which can not be programmed with  much memory safe languages. But that’s a whole different story)

Tl;dr
While it might seem that we should no longer have any memory issues there still impossible to completely eliminate.

Comment: The first part is plain nonsense. It's perfectly possible to write buffer-safe code in " unsafe"  languages. It has to be, because CPU's execute "unsafe" assembly, yet it's possible for safe languages to exist. And in fact we do have software proofs. We even have an entire OS (seL4) kernel that's proven safe.

Comment: Proof in this case would be mathematically in nature. I have not seen it and I have been taught due to the halting problem you can not have it. This is also part of why you can never be sure buffer overflows errors can not occur. While you can make it near impossible, making it completely impossible is not an option.

Answer (score 0):

From my point of view, buffer overflows exists nowadays because you have old code running services everywhere. It is true that languages such as rust are focused on memory management and is difficult to exploit them, but there are other systems, for example, Apache Server that is written in C, that is potentially more impacted by overflows attacks.

On the other hand, overflows exist because of the way the operating system is designed with stack and heaps. I don't know right now any operating system that doesn't have these elements implemented on it.

Comment: The operating system I build for a 8088 did not use a stack or heap. So that’s atleast one that doesn’t. But you are correct that most systems use them.

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 different points of view on your question.

1. Can attackers rely on buffer overflow to find exploitable bugs ?

IMHO it is no longer the favorite tool of black hat hackers. Except on trivial (school) use cases, finding a buffer overflow requires a heavy job, and building an exploit above it still needs more work. There are many simpler ways by trying other well known bugs in various libraries, and even black hats know that the weaker security element for a computer lies between a keyboard and a chair... Social engeneering leads to cheaper ways...

2. Is it still important to bore students with that ?

YES! Many parts of low level tools (OS, compilers, system libraries) have to use low level languages (assembly, C, low level C++). The strength of a software depends on the quality of all the underlying *tools* it uses, and the strength of a piece of code depends on the care of the programming team. As a now old dinosaur in the IT world, I have too often seen many codes where the security has not been a first class concern. That is the reason why it is still **essential** when teaching programming concepts, to insist on security best practices and the risk of not respecting them.